# Spawn Rscript ENOENT error while running R script in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, rscript

index.js file

```
R("message.R")
.data("hello world", 20)
.call(function(err, d) {
     if (err) console.log('err:', err);
     console.log('hiiii:', d);
   });
```

message.R file

```
Print('ankit is here')
```

In command line, when running `node index.js`, getting error spawn Rscript ENOENT

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

> Error: spawn Rscript ENOENT
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3) Emitted 'error' event at:
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
>       [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)

Answer (score 1):

If you are also facing the same issues, after spending 4-5 hour time, I get to know that we need to install R in your local machine. the procedure of installing R is as mentioned in the link.[install R in ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-16-04-2)

After that type R, 
you will get R environment

Install

```
install.packages("dplyr");
```